# jQuery: alter DIV that shares class with another DIV (but still owns a unique class also) only if some conditions were met

Tags: jquery

First of all I'm terribly sorry for the complicated subject but I don't know how to express my question shorter.

Say I have two buttons and two DIVs.

The first DIV has class `class_1` and the second DIV has two classes: `class_1 class_2`.

The first button should only alter both `class_1` and `class_1 class_2` DIVs if the second button was previously clicked. Otherwise it should only alter `class_1` DIV.

I see the solution in setting a variable and alter just one or both DIVs according to its value. But can't achieve the desired result, I'm afraid because my script can't affect a variable placed outside the function.

Here's my progress:

```
<style>
.class_1, .class_2, .on1, .on2 {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2); color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: inline-block; height: 100px; width: 100px;
    text-align: center; line-height: 100px; margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
.on1, .on2 {cursor: pointer;}
</style>

<div>
    <div class="on1">Class 1 on</div> <div class="on2">Class 2 on</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="class_1">Class 1</div> <div class="class_1 class_2">Class 2</div>
</div>

<script>
var class_2_flag = "off";
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".on2").click(function() {
            var class_2_flag = "on";
        });
        jQuery(".on1").click(function() {
            if (class_2_flag == "on") {
        jQuery(".class_1").css("background", "skyblue");
        jQuery(".class_1.class_2").css("background", "skyblue");
            }
        else {
            jQuery(".class_1").css("background", "steelblue");
            jQuery(".class_1.class_2").css("background", "skyblue");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And here's the fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97sxgrtd/) *(updated and working properly thanks to @**haxxxton**'s reply)*.

Seems that **Class 2 on** button can't access the `class_2_flag` variable, while setting it only inside its function. So I can't even check if I'm thinking in the right direction.

Comment: change `var class_2_flag = "on";` to `class_2_flag = "on";` you're redeclaring you variable by prefixing it with `var` which is overriding the global.. although the global is usually frowned upon [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97sxgrtd/22/)

Comment: Should I change it everywhere or just at the specific position? Seems that removing `var` from both the 1st and the 4th lines of the script has the same positive effect as altering just 4th line, but I'm afraid both results are not the same. Anyway, could you please repost your reply as the answer so that I could upvote it? Because it is a working one, thank you!

Comment: Done, do please look at the recommendation in the answer regarding scoping of your variable :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. However, on `Line 4` of your JS code, you're redeclaring your `class_2_flag` variable by prefixing it with `var`, which is overriding your global declaration within the scope of the click event.

If you are confident you want to stick with using a global ([It is generally discouraged](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)). Then you just need to remove the `var` prefix from `Line 4`.

As you rightly pointed out, you can remove the `var` prefix from `Line 1` too, however, for code clarity, and validation you should leave it.

If i can make a recommendation, it would be to scope your `class_2_flag` *within* your document ready function, as it will remove it from the global scope, but still provide access to all the functions declared within. Something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var class_2_flag = "off"; // us now inside the ready function scope
    jQuery(".on2").click(function() {
        class_2_flag = "on"; // we are also within the ready function scope, so do not prefix with `var`
    });
    jQuery(".on1").click(function() {
        if (class_2_flag == "on") {
            jQuery(".class_1").css("background", "skyblue");
            jQuery(".class_1.class_2").css("background", "skyblue");
        } else {
            jQuery(".class_1").css("background", "steelblue");
            jQuery(".class_1.class_2").css("background", "skyblue");
        }
    });
});
```